# What are the characteristics of a $\Theta(n \log n)$ time complexity algorithm?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, time-complexity, intuition

Sometimes it's easy to identify the time complexity of an algorithm my examining it carefully. Algorithms with two nested loops of $N$ are obviously $N^2$. Algorithms that explore all the possible combinations of $N$ groups of two values are obviously $2^N$.

However I don't know how to "spot" an algorithm with $\Theta(N \log N)$ complexity. A recursive mergesort implementation, for example, is one. What are the common characteristics of mergesort or other $\Theta(N \log N)$ algorithms that would give me a clue if I was analyzing one?

I'm sure there is more than one way an algorithm can be of $\Theta(N \log N)$ complexity, so any and all answers are appreciated. BTW I'm seeking general characteristics and tips, not rigorous proofs.

Comment: $O(\log n)$ means tree.

Comment: [Related question.](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/581/intuition-for-logarithmic-complexity)

Comment: @PratikDeoghare: Not necessarily.

Comment: @Raphael I meant mostly! :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your archetypical $\Theta(n \log n)$ is a **divide-and-conquer** algorithm, which divides (and recombines) the work in **linear time** and recurses over the pieces. Merge sort works that way: spend $O(n)$ time splitting the input into two roughly equal pieces, recursively sort each piece, and spend $\Theta(n)$ time combining the two sorted halves.

Intuitively, continuing the divide-and-conquer idea, each division stage takes linear time in total, because the increase in the number of pieces to divide exactly matches the decrease in the size of the pieces, since the time taken by division is linear. The total running time is the product of the total cost of a division stage multiplied by the number of division stages. Since the size of the pieces is halved at each time, there are $\log_2(n)$ division stages, so the total running time is $n \cdot \log(n)$. (Up to a multiplicative constant, the base of the logarithm is irrelevant.)

Putting it in equations (), one way to estimate the running time $T(n)$ of such an algorithm is to express it recursively: $T(n) = 2 T(n/2) + \Theta(n)$. It's clear that this algorithm takes more than linear time, and we can see how much more by dividing by $n$:
$$ \frac{T(n)}{n} = \frac{T(n/2)}{n/2} + \Theta(1) $$
When $n$ doubles, $T(n)/n$ increases by a constant amount: $T(n)/n$ increases logarithmically, or in other words, $T(n) = \Theta(n \log n)$.

This is an instance of a more general pattern: the [master theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem). For any recursive algorithm that divides its input of size $n$ into $a$ pieces of size $n/b$ and takes a time $f(n)$ to perform the division and recombination, the running time satisfies $T(n) = a \cdot T(n/b) + f(n)$. This leads to a closed form that depends on the values of $a$ and $b$ and the shape of $f$. If $a = b$ and $f(n) = \Theta(n)$, the master theorem states that $T(n) = \Theta(n \log n)$.

Comment: To summarise: algorithms that do away with constant fractions of the search space at a time will exhibit logarithmic terms. The other factors depend on how long it takes to perform the doing away.

Comment: example: quicksort average case $O(n \log n)$

Answer (score 11):

Two other categories of algorithms that take $\Theta(n \log n)$ time:

Algorithms where each item is processed in turn, and it takes logarithmic time to process each item (e.g. HeapSort or many of the plane sweep computational geometry algorithms).

Algorithms where the running time is dominated by a sorting pre-processing step. (For example, in Kruskal's algorithm for minimum spanning tree, we may sort the edges by weight as the first step).

Comment: Upvoted for the first paragraph. The second seems redundant, since the linearithmic sorting algorithms we know are either divide & conquer or heapsort. An example for the first category is search of $n$ objects in a binary search tree (or sorted array) of size $n$; on a more abstract level, that can also be seen as divide & conquer, though.

Comment: @Raphael I know that sorting is redundant with the categories of running times already given. The point is that sorting is sometimes the "bottleneck" and algorithms where at first blush the question isn't about sorting may still have the run-time because sorting is required.

Answer (score 9):

Another category: Algorithms in which the *output* has size $\Theta(n \log n)$, and therefore $\Theta(n \log n)$ running time is *linear* in the *output size*.

Although the details of such algorithms often use divide-and-conquer techniques, they don't necessarily have to. The run-time fundamentally comes from the question being asked, and so I think it is worth mentioning separately.

This comes up in data structures which are based on an augmented binary search tree, where each node stores a linear size data structure to search over the leaves in that node's subtree. Such data structures come up often in geometric range searching, and are often based on a *decomposition scheme*. 
See [Agarwal's Survey](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.94.8006).

For a concrete example, consider the [range-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_tree), built to answer two dimensional orthogonal range queries. Although the space was later reduced using some compression techniques to pack multiple objects into a single word, the textbook (and most intuitive) version of the data structure requires $O(n \log n)$ space (each leaf is stored in an auxiliary structure at each node on the path from the leaf to the root, or in $O(\log n)$ places), and the construction algorithm takes time *linear in the space requirement*.

Comment: An example would be finding the n-th prime using a sieve, because you'd need a sieve of size $\theta(n log n)$.

Answer (score 6):

A complexity of $O(n\log n)$ arises from divide and conquer algorithms which divide their input into $k$ pieces of roughly equal size in time $O(n)$, operate on these pieces recursively, and then combine them in time $O(n)$. If you only operate on some of the pieces, the running time drops to $O(n)$.

Answer (score 5):

Those are typically algorithms of the "divide and conquer" variety, where the cost of dividing and combining subsolutions isn't "too large". Take a look at [this FAQ](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2789/solving-or-approximating-recurrence-relations-for-sequences-of-numbers/2823#2823) to see what kinds of recurrences give rise to this behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

Typically, Divide-and-conquer algorithms will yield O(N log N) complexity.

Answer (score -1):

A generic example of a *loop* (**not** an algorithm per se) that runs in $O(n \log n)$ is the following:

```
for (i = 0; i < constant; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < n; j++){
        // Do some O(1) stuff on the input
    }
}

// Alternative Variant:
for (i = 0; i < constant; i++){
    for(j = n; j < constant; j++){
        // Do some O(1) stuff on the input
    }
}
```

(note that this nested loops are ***not*** $O(n^2)$. Also note that it isn't divide-and-conquer nor recursive.)

I can't give a concrete example of an algorithm that uses this loop, but it comes up often when coding custom algorithms.

Comment: Yes, these are both $O(n\log n)$ but for the trivial reason that the bound is not tight. The first one is $\Theta(n)$ and the second is $\Theta(1)$ (or $\Theta(|n|)$ if $n$ can be negative).

Comment: I thought it useful to mention, since it does come up in practice but every search for "$O(n \log n)$" is mostly "divide-and-conquer" examples like e.g. merge sort.

Comment: additionally, the original question didn't ask for big-theta.

Comment: Sure but **any** algorithm that runs in linear or constant time is $O(n\log n)$, as well as being $O(2^{2^n})$ and $O(\text{almost anything else})$. Your answer has nothing to do with logarithms. If you want to make the point that the question should be asking about $\Theta(n\log n)$ rather than $O(n\log n)$ then either make that point explicitly as comment to the question or, even better, edit the question.

Comment: I wanted to make the point that I **actually** searched the internet for $O(n \log n)$ to see if the loop in my answer, that I had to come up with for an actual answer to an actual programming problem that was required to run in $O(n \log n)$, was actually $O(n \log n)$ or not. And most information around deals with divide-and-conquer algorithms, so it would be worth mentioning. I do not pretend my answer to be the archetypical $O(n \log n)$ algorithm.