# Confusion regarding several time complexities including the logarithm

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, runtime-analysis, landau-notation

I am new to Advanced Algorithms and I have studied various samples on Google and StackExchange. What I understand is:

1. We use $O(\log n)$ complexity when  there is division of any $n$ number on each recursion (especially in divide and conquer).
2. I know that for binary search, we have time complexity $O(n \log n)$, I understood $\log n$ is because each time it halves the full $n$ size number list in a recursive manner until it finds the required element. But why is it multiplied with $n$ even we just traverse half of the $n$ size element for each execution so why we multiply $\log n$ with $n$?
3. Please give me any example explaining the complexity $O(n^2 \log n)$. I hope this will help me in understanding much better the above two questions.

Comment: Maybe you just chose the wrong word but when you say, "We *use* $O(\log n)$ complexity," that suggests a significant misunderstanding. It suggests making a choice: for example, you might choose to implement an algorithm using linear programming, divide & conquer or some other method. But you don't choose the complexity of a given algorithm, just as you don't choose the prime factors of a given integer. The actual complexity of any specific algorithm is a fixed property of that algorithm. You might choose to use an algorithm with some given complexity but you can't choose the complexity per se.

Comment: Have you looked in a textbook on the matter, esp. for the definitions? Have you checked out our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/599/reference-answers-to-frequently-asked-questions)? There is also [this question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/581/intuition-for-logarithmic-complexity). Finally, let it be said that complexity classes are *not* defined via algorithms of that runtime, and that any given algorithm may "be" in different classes depending on what you count (cf comparisons vs swaps for Quicksort).

Answer (score 4):

1. You are correct in thinking [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search) is $O(\log n)$, it shouldn't be multiplied by $n$.
2. Popular (comparison-based) [sorting algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) are $O(n \log n)$.
3. [3SUM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3sum) (i.e. find 3 elements in an array that sums to zero) using binary search is $O(n^2 \log n)$.

   The pseudo-code:

   ```
   For each element
     For each other element
       Do a binary search for the 3rd element that will result in a zero sum.
   ```

   Although the problem can be solved in $O(n^2)$ in a different way, this should still serve as a decent example.

**Explanation of merge-sort complexity:**

Merge-sort, for example, splits the array into 2 parts repeatedly (similar to binary search), but there are some differences:

- Binary search throws away the other half, where merge-sort processes both
- Binary search consists of a simple $O(1)$ check at each point, where-as merge-sort needs to do an $O(n)$ merge. This should already make the $O(\log n)$ vs $O(n \log n)$ make sense.

For a quick check, ask how many work, on average, is done for each element.
Note that a single merge is linear time, thus $O(1)$ per element.
You recurse down $O(\log n)$ times and, at each step there's a merge, so each element is involved in $O(\log n)$ merges.
And there are $O(n)$ elements.
Thus we have a time complexity of $O(n \log n)$.

There is also the more mathematical analysis: ([source](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/How_do_you_calculate_time_complexity_for_merge_sort))

> Let $T(n)$ the time used to sort n elements. As we can perform separation and merging in linear time, it takes $cn$ time to perform these two steps, for some constant $c$. So,
>   $T(n) = 2T(n/2) + cn$.

From here you work your way down to $T(1)$, and the remaining terms gives you your $O(n \log n)$ running time. Or use the [master theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem).

If both of these are unclear, it should be easy enough to find another resource explaining the complexity of merge-sort.

Comment: Thaks for the reply.Now i have the doubt that in merge sort we have complexity O(nlogn). I understood this 'logn' it is because of division of input array in to two halves each time but again why to multiply it with 'n' (may be this n complexity is for comparison among two elements but we compare only two elements at a time so why we multiply 'n' by 'logn') please explain this.

Comment: ^I suggest you to go through Introduction to algorithms by CLRS. Merge sort has been explained quite well in that.

Comment: @shekharshekhawat Edited with an explanation of merge-sort.

Comment: @shekharshekhawat Check out any introduction on algorithm analysis, e.g. CLRS or Sedgewick. There is a mathematical formalism to it. By applying this formalism repeatedly you will develop the intuition you search. There is no (reliable) shortcut.